# Django+fcgi+Nginx hyperlinks errors

Tags: python, django, nginx, hyperlink

Good day!
I'm pretty new to Django. My project contains several apps (catalog, parts, registration etc.) and that, how main url.py looks like:

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
url(r'^registration/', include('registration.urls', namespace='registration', app_name='registration')),
url(r'^parts/', include('parts.urls', namespace='parts', app_name='parts')),
url(r'^catalog/', include('catalog.urls', namespace='catalog', app_name='catalog')),
url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='base.html'), name='base'),]
```

And that how looks one of apps urls.py:

```
`urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<username>[\w ]+)?$', views.catalog, name='catalog'),
    url(r'^transactions/$', views.catalog_transactions, name='catalog_transactions'),`
etc. etc.
```

Everything worked fine on django testserver, but when i tried to run it with fcgi+Nginx, i've stucked with hypelink problem. When i click on one of hyperlinks on first page it somehow keeps its address and when i try to click another link it appends it to first one.
For example, if my first click goes to `ip_address:port/catalog/` then other hyperlink on that page transforms into `ip_address:port/catalog/some_page/` instead of `ip_address:port/some_page/`

I use `{% url %}` tags for all hyperlinks in my templates, so links look like `<a href="{% url catalog:some_page %}">Some_page</a>`

That, how looks my Nginx configuration:

```
`server {
        listen 9090 default_server;
        server_name mtsk.tools.com;
        merge_slashes off;
        location / {
                fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:99;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }
        location /static/ {
                root /Django/Parts/;
        }}`
```

Django version is 1.8
Nginx version is 1.11.10
fcgi version is 2.4.0-2

Did anyone stucked with similar problem?
Thanks in advance)

EDIT
Also i tried to run some test django-project on that server, and they worked fine. But these projects had only one app per project

Answer (score 0):

From Django website:

> FastCGI support is deprecated and will be removed in Django 1.9.

See http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html for uwsgi.

Comment: Yup, i know, but server i'm using has fcgi preinstalled and i've encountered some issues with installing uwsgi on it. So i decided to use Django 1.8, which supports fcgi. Also, test projects i tried to use with such setup worked fine, but they had only one app per project.